# Connecting to Docker local network with BIRD

Tags: docker

I have a Docker container running WireGuard (https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-wireguard)

Config:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  wireguard:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: my-wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
      - SERVERURL=193.168.227.155
      - SERVERPORT=51820
      - PEERS=1
      - PEERDNS=1.1.1.1
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0
      - ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0
    volumes:
      - /home/wireguard:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
    sysctls:
      - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I need to run BIRD for clients connected with WireGuard

Config:

```
log syslog all;

router id 10.13.13.0;

protocol kernel {
    scan time 60;
    ipv4 {
        import none;
        export none;
    };
}

protocol device {
    scan time 60;
}

protocol static {
    ipv4;
    include "subnet.txt";
    include "ip.txt";
    include "my.txt";
}

protocol bgp {
    local 10.13.13.0 as 64999;
    neighbor 10.13.13.2 as 64999;
    passive off;
    ipv4 {
        import none;
        export all;
        next hop self;
        };
}

protocol bgp {
    local 10.13.13.0 as 64999;
    neighbor 10.13.13.3 as 64999;
    passive off;
    ipv4 {
        import none;
        export all;
        next hop self;
        };
}
```

With this config BIRD cannot connect, I get "bgp1: Socket error: bind: Cannot assign requested address" errors

I understand that additional configuration is required for this to work, but I'm really unfamiliar with Docker networking